# How am I signed in on youtube.com just by signing into Gmail?

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, google-signin

I was browsing Gmail and went to youtube.com and realized I was signed in. I never actually signed into youtube.com. How does YouTube make me signed in there?

I'm curious about how this is implemented engineering-wise and the security techniques used.

Comment: Youtube is owned by Google, they unified their accounts. You can also go to your google account and and it will show you all the youtube videos you watched while signed in to gmail.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, I'm more of asking about how the engineering and security mechanisms work behind the scenes.